# MYSQL DateTime vs strtotime string held in database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to work out which is the best solution for me - i am making a roster application and have been working with the string, but think it may be beneficial to switch to the datetime type - currently working with dates is getting hard, trying to put the shifts onto a roster without doing a query for every single cell.

Answer (score 5):

If you have something that's a date or a date/time then it's always better to use the right datatype for that. You get many benefits in terms of being able to do functions on it, having comparisons work, etc. It will also map well to the date/time types in your preferred language.

Answer (score 0):

I think storing the dates as a datetime field makes the most sense, but I agree, it's not the easiest to deal with. I have a function in my date library that turns MySQL datetime values into a PHP timestamp.

```
function datetime_to_timestamp($datetime)
{
    $timestamp = strtotime( $datetime );
    return $timestamp;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

PHP function strtotime($datetime) converts mysql datetime fields to unix timestamp and works really well. Why using an extra wrapper?